# Как сделать такой range slider

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте.  В проекте имеется вот такой слайдер

```js
$('#slideOne').on("click", function() {
  $('#slideLabel').toggleClass('toggle-class');
})
```

```css
.slideOne {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 215px;
  max-height: 16px;
  background-color: #39a4ea;
  margin-top: 7vh !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.slideOne label {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1c81c4;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  left: 185px;
}

.toggle-class {
  background-color: #a7cb6f !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-toggle col-md-8 col-sm-8">

  <div class="slideOne" id="slideLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="slideOne" name="check" />
    <label for="slideOne"></label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Как вы можете видеть, это чекбокс и немного Jquery. Необходимо этому слайдеру придать вид как на рисунке ниже. [image: Необходимый слайдер]

У данного слайдера присутствуем срединная позиция и я не знаю, каким образом можно это реализовать, пожалуйста, помогите.

Пробовал решение от сюда [Стилизовать input type=range перед ползунком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671502/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-input-type-range-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Но при моих размерах все варианты странно себя ведут:

[image: Непонятно от куда вылезающий background]

Из рисунка видно, что перед ползунком голубого цвета, цвет слайдера бирюзовый, однако перед этим он цвета фона самого слайдера. Это проявляется только при изменении ширины слайдера взятого из примера. Как я могу это исправить? И Как стилизовать сам бегунок, сделав его выступающим? Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Стилизовать input type=range перед ползунком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671502/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-input-type-range-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: я б использовал 2 checkbox и стилизацию для них.

Comment: А как на моем примере можно реализовать 2 чекбокса? @klifort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте начальный класс для середины, и при клике удалите его, например:

```js
$('#slideOne').on("click", function() {
  $('#slideLabel').removeClass('middle-class');
  $('#slideLabel').toggleClass('toggle-class');
})
```

```css
.slideOne {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 215px;
  max-height: 16px;
  background-color: #39a4ea;
  margin-top: 7vh !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.slideOne label {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1c81c4;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  left: 185px;
}

.toggle-class {
  background-color: #a7cb6f !important;
}

.slideOne.middle-class input[type=checkbox]+label {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17.5px;
}
.slideOne.middle-class:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:50%;
  background-color: #a7cb6f !important;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-toggle col-md-8 col-sm-8">

  <div class="slideOne middle-class" id="slideLabel">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="slideOne" name="check" />
    <label for="slideOne"></label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Это выглядит и работает здорово! Не могли бы Вы также подсказать, как сделать переход бегунка на середину? Добавить еще один класс?

Comment: Этот же класс и можете использовать, просто нужно прописать условие при котором он будет на середине. На сколько я понимаю он должен быть только при загрузке на середине, а потом даже не знаю при каких действиях его логично было бы ставить на середину, это уже зависит от вашего контекста

Comment: В целом, Вы правы: середина нужна только при загрузке страницы :) Спасибо большое!

Comment: не получается реализовать нужное условие что то:( Подскажите, как его правильно сделать, пожалуйста @kizoso

Comment: он сделан выше, код вы видите, что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: больше спасибо Вам за вашу отзывчивость) Попросил коллегу помочь, он показал как нужно) В комментарии скинул код

Answer (score 1):

Следующий код делает тоже, что код kizoso, но с серединным классом :)

```
    $(function () {
                  var checkbox = $("#slideOne"), 
                  current = 1, 
                  direction = true, 
                  classes = ["toggle-class", "middle-class", ""], 
                  states = [false, false, true];
                        ///
                 checkbox.click(function () {
                        if (current + 1 > 2) direction = false;
                        if (0 > current - 1) direction = true;

                        var cursor = direction ? ++ current : -- current;

                        checkbox.prop("checked", states[cursor]);

                        $("#slideLabel").attr("class", "slideOne " + classes[cursor]);
                        });
                    });
```

Просто попробуйте это, вместо примера выше, если Вам это может помочь:)