# Необходимо сделать range slider с использованием jquery

Tags: jquery, css3

[image: Вот такой дизайн. Хочется сделать его максимально просто без jquery_ui.]

Вот такой дизайн.Два зеленых бегунка. Конечные точки - серые круги, под которыми label с максимальным и минимальным значением. Между бегунками заливка зеленым цветом. Хочется сделать его максимально просто без jquery_ui. И вообще как работают такие слайдеры. Читаю, но все как то не то. Хотелось бы найти how to step by step. Чтоб простенько и с нуля. Чтоб понять как возыметь ПОЛНУЮ власть над этим компонентом.Можно ли это сделать с использованием flexbox и dragable?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Делаем самопальный range slider](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748494/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-range-slider)

Answer (score 1):

Можно и на чистом `css` сделать. Не используя `javascript`.

Стили не так как в вшей картинке. Это можете поменять на ваш вкус.
А как это сделать можете посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671502/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-input-type-range-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC).

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
#slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

/* The slider itself */
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;   
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Здесь использовал несколько строк `javascript` для того что бы под слайдером показало текущее значение.

Comment: А как сделать 2 бегунка?

Comment: @LutiyCsharp https://codepen.io/sakamies/pen/qOEGLJ

Comment: @LutiyCsharp И еще одно, в вопросе вообще не было сказано про 2 бегунка, задайте вопрос так что бы можно было дать однозначный ответ. А не так что бы после ответа часами прояснить что к чему.

Comment: @LutiyCsharp Ну про 2 бегунка я уже дал ссылку здесь

Comment: Razmik, Ок, начинаю складывать пазлы, Ваш ответ, плюс ваша ссылка на стилизацию заливки за бегунком, плюс ссылка на codepen. Спасибо, сейчас попробую соединить все вместе.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел на гитхабе http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/  - очень хорошо настраивается и масштабируется. В нем простой файл css и понятный файл .js, который просто отредактировать. Зависит от общей библиотеки jQuery.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/215844)

Comment: написал расширенный ответ но замахался код редактировать в этом редакторе потратив 20 драгоценных минут нажал отмену. Есть текстовик с ответом и кодом. Если кто сможет его здесь разместить вышлю на почту. poluusver - мой скайп.

Comment: Разместите как сможете и напишите коммент, я отредактирую