# Cоздание индивидуального ползунка "<input type="range">"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Здравствуйте, необходимо сделать ползунок с индивидуальным дизайном.
Поэтому    `input type=range`    не подойдет, пробовал использовать jQueryUI, но он тоже не предоставляет нужный уровень кастомотизации. В итоге пришел к варианты создание ползунка из двух объектов тега `div`, поэтому вопрос такой:

Существуют ли готовые библиотеки или же плагины позволяющие настроить собственный ползунок, или же придется все писать в ручную?

Заместо ползунка должна быть грубо говоря картинка

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для того что бы стилизировать `<input type="range">` надо знать из каких частей для браузера он состоит.

Вот картинка. На котором показаны части `range`. И каждая часть можно стилизировать отдельно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример с индивидуальным дизайном. Здесь на `range thumb` наложен `div` с картинкой. Правда здесь есть и `js` код для еще более красивой реализации прокрутки ползунка. Но вообще можно задать стили и без этого.

Здесь картинка другая чем автор хотел. но вообще принцип наверное будет понятен.

```js
function showValue(val,slidernum,vertical) {
    /* setup variables for the elements of our slider */
    var thumb = document.getElementById("sliderthumb" + slidernum);
    var shell = document.getElementById("slidershell" + slidernum);
    var track = document.getElementById("slidertrack" + slidernum);
    var fill = document.getElementById("sliderfill" + slidernum);
    var rangevalue = document.getElementById("slidervalue" + slidernum);
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider" + slidernum);
    
    var pc = val/(slider.max - slider.min); /* the percentage slider value */
    var thumbsize = 40; /* must match the thumb size in your css */
    var bigval = 250; /* widest or tallest value depending on orientation */
    var smallval = 40; /* narrowest or shortest value depending on orientation */
    var tracksize = bigval - thumbsize;
    var fillsize = 16;
    var filloffset = 10;
    var bordersize = 2;
    var loc = vertical ? (1 - pc) * tracksize : pc * tracksize;
    var degrees = 360 * pc;
    var rotation = "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)";
    
    rangevalue.innerHTML = val;
    
    thumb.style.webkitTransform = rotation;
    thumb.style.MozTransform = rotation;
    thumb.style.msTransform = rotation;
    
    fill.style.opacity = pc + 0.2 > 1 ? 1 : pc + 0.2;
    
    rangevalue.style.top = (vertical ? loc : 0) + "px";
    rangevalue.style.left = (vertical ? 0 : loc) + "px";
    thumb.style.top =  (vertical ? loc : 0) + "px";
    thumb.style.left = (vertical ? 0 : loc) + "px";
    fill.style.top = (vertical ? loc + (thumbsize/2) : filloffset + bordersize) + "px";
    fill.style.left = (vertical ? filloffset + bordersize : 0) + "px";
    fill.style.width = (vertical ? fillsize : loc + (thumbsize/2)) + "px";
    fill.style.height = (vertical ? bigval - filloffset - fillsize - loc : fillsize) + "px";
    shell.style.height = (vertical ? bigval : smallval) + "px";
    shell.style.width = (vertical ? smallval : bigval) + "px";
    track.style.height = (vertical ? bigval - 4 : fillsize) + "px"; /* adjust for border */
    track.style.width = (vertical ? fillsize : bigval - 4) + "px"; /* adjust for border */
    track.style.left = (vertical ? filloffset + bordersize : 0) + "px";
    track.style.top = (vertical ? 0 : filloffset + bordersize) + "px";
}
/* we often need a function to set the slider values on page load */
function setValue(val,num,vertical) {
    document.getElementById("slider"+num).value = val;
    showValue(val,num,vertical);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){   
  setValue(88,1,false);
})
```

```css
.slider{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  overflow:visible;
  z-index:100;
}


.slidershell {
  border:0 none;
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  overflow:visible;
}

.slidertrack {
  border:2px outset #666;
  border-radius:4px;
  position:absolute;
}

.sliderfill {
  border:2px solid #00767f;
  border-radius:4px;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.2;
  pointer-events:none;
  background:#00767f;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,#005555,#006699);
}

.sliderthumb {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-image:url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/358203/thumb.png');
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position:0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color:transparent;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  border:0 none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.slidervalue {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  border:0 none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}

/*For IE*/
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0 none;
  background:transparent;
  color:transparent;
  overflow:visible;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width:100%;height:100%;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0 none;
    background:transparent;
    color:transparent;
    overflow:visible;
}
input[type=range] {
    width:100%;height:100%;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0 none;
    background:transparent;
    color:transparent;
    overflow:visible;
}

input[type=range].slidervertical {
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
    opacity:0.01;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background:transparent;
  border:transparent;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
    
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  width:40px;height:40px;
  border-radius:0px;
  border:0 none;
  background:transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  width:40px;height:40px;
  border-radius:0px;
  border:0 none;
  background:transparent;
}    
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:0px;
  border:0 none;
  background:transparent;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {background:transparent;border:0 none;}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {background:transparent;border:0 none;}
input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip { display: none;}

body {font-family:sans-serif;}
.slider2column, td, tr, th {
  width:400px;
  border:0 none !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="slider2column">
<tr><td>
<div class="slidershell" id="slidershell1">
    <div class="sliderfill" id="sliderfill1"></div>
    <div class="slidertrack" id="slidertrack1"></div>
    <div class="sliderthumb" id="sliderthumb1"></div>
    <div class="slidervalue" id="slidervalue1">0</div>
    <input class="slider" id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0"
    oninput="showValue(value,1,false);" onchange="showValue(value,1,false);"/>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

И в добавок вот хороший [сайт](http://www.cssportal.com/style-input-range/) для визуальной обработки собственного ползунка.

Вот другой вариант только с индивидуальным изображением на `thumb` с не стандартными границами.

Подробно об этом.

> 1. Задаем ширину и высоту для `thumb` с размерами той картинки который мы хотим наложить на него.
> 2. Берем картинку но обязательно без фона, и наложим его на `thumb` с помощью `background`.

В примере будем использовать вот эту картинку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дождались.)))**

*Вот и сам пример.*

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #367ebd;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  background: #3071a9;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2a6495;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #3071a9;
  border: 0.2px solid #010101;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QneFV.png) center center no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -23px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Comment: наверно нужно было добавить, что заместо thumb должна быть грубо говоря картинка, которая больше чем scrollbar

Comment: @GicO Не понял вас.

Comment: мне нужно создать такой вот ползунок
https://pp.userapi.com/c840330/v840330260/484b9/Qx15sAcg4zI.jpg

Comment: Я извиняюсь за оффтоп, но как сослаться на ваш ник, если он содержит пробел?

Comment: @GicO пробелы надо убрать, и еще если пишете под моим вопросом или ответом то ник можете пропустить, понял что вы хотите. изменю ответ.

Comment: спасибо за просвещение, буду ждать изменений, а сам пока тоже продолжу искать!

Comment: @GicO Вот два примера того что вы хотели. Уже не надо искать. Это вполне вам устроит.

Comment: А можно скриншоты того, как эти примеры должны выглядеть? А то я не уверен, что они у меня выглядят правильно)

Comment: @andreymal а вы на каком браузере смотрите? И почему не уверены? покажите как у вас все это выглядит?

Comment: @RazGalstyan почему бы вам не показать, как это выглядит у вас?) А то вот лет через пять все браузеры обновятся и селекторы попеределают, и фиг поймёшь, остались ли примеры рабочими или какая-то мелочь отображается не так, как задумывалось)

Comment: @andreymal ну тогда кому будет нужно на своем сайте переделает. а если не сможет задаст здесь вопрос. И вопрос не будет дубликатом)))))

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, это прям то что нужно!
 У меня еще вопрос, а чтобы цвет отличался слева как на примере с квадратом, нужно уже JS подключать так?

Comment: @GicO Посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671502/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-input-type-range-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/671507#671507

Comment: Я понял, что там для webkit'а используется box-shadow, но когда Я добавляю его себе, тень у меня получается больше слайдера https://pp.userapi.com/c841032/v841032392/5cbbc/2B8g5b0cGMc.jpg